# generate entities from database : table missing

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I would like to use the symfony command line :

```
app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force MyBUNDLE xml
```

Doing this, everything is generated but one table "hasrole" that is a junction between two tables User and Role.

What is happening ? Do I miss something ?

Note : I used to work with Symfony 2.3 (this table was generated) now I work with Symfony 2.7. Something's changed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is just a conjunction table without other columns but only ids, it will be mapped with a `ManyToMany` between two entities involved (`User` and `Role`). Please check them out.

Comment: that is right, but in Symfony 2.3, the hasRole table was generated as an entity. Do u know when it changed ?

Comment: @mlwacosmos I suppose this is due to doctrine. btw is the desired situation and has no sense to generate an entity only with ids

Comment: I don't know why you didn't get any votes, but here it is one four years later. Thanks for sharing.